# Sending emails with "Rails 2.2.2 + Gmail"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to send emails with "Rails 2.2.2 + Gmail"? I have tried several methods with smtp_tls, but not succeed. Who can give me an available tsl plugin download link and an actionmailer smtp_setting?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 2.2.1 ships with an option to enable it if you're running Ruby 1.8.7.

To set it all up, in config/initializers/smtp_gmail.rb, make sure to set `:enable_starttls_auto` to true.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name => "noreply@gmail_or_your_google_domain.com",
  :password => "chucknorris"
}
```

Otherwise try [ActionMailerTLS](http://github.com/openrain/action_mailer_tls/tree/) gem or plugin.

Comment: Worked like a charm man, thanks!  I prefer using this to Heroku's instructions, since it keeps things portable.

Answer (score 0):

here is a specific lib for this http://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail  Its just ruby so integrating it into your rails scripts should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Pony with the [gmail fix](http://blog.jpoz.net/2009/09/02/gmail-heroku-sinatra.html), if you only need something lightweight.